# Storing values from STL vector to another vector

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, vector, stl

I stuck at one point and need some help.

I have a `STL` vector with the following values:

```
[1, 17, 2, 18, 3, 19, 1, 17, 2, 18, 3, 19, 1, 17, 2, 18, 3, 19].
```

note that first six values in a vector (i.e. 1, 17, 2, 18, 3, 19 ) can be considered as one block. So this vector has 3 blocks each with the values as described above.

Now, I want to organize this vector in a following way:

```
[1, 17, 1, 17, 1, 17, 2, 18, 2, 18, 2, 18, 3, 19, 3, 19, 3, 19]
```

.

So essentially I am picking first two values (i.e. 1, 17) from each block first and store them sequentially 3 times (basically # of blocks which in this case is 3). I then go on to pick next two values (i.e. 2, 18) and continue.

How do I achieve this..?

Any help  will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Must it be done in-place, or can you make a new vector with the result?

Comment: yes. you can store result in a new vector.

Comment: Have you tried by yourself, where are you stuck?

Comment: I think I will have to use nested for loop but I just can't figure out how.

Answer (score 0):

Sound quite easy once you figure out the exact mapping. So external loop is the number of chunks in every block since that's the number of final groups, middle loop goes over each original block while inner loop just goes through every element of a chunk. Final result should be something like (untested):

```
std::vector organized;
organized.reserve(data.size());
const int blockSize = 6;
const int subBlockSize = 2;
assert(data.size()%blockCount == 0 && blockSize%subBlockSize == 0);
const int blockCount = data.size()/blockSize;
const int subBlockCount = blockSize/subBlockSize;

for (int i = 0; i < subBlockCount; ++i)
  for (int j = 0; j < blockCount; ++j)
    for (int k = 0; k < subBlockSize; ++k)
      organized.push_back(subBlockSize*i + blockSize*j + k);
```

Comment: Thank you. in this line " const int blockCount = data.size()/blockCount), did you mean data.size()/blockSize..?

Answer (score 0):

Just create a function `shuffle(i)` that takes an index into the new array, and returns an index from the original array:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int list[] = { 1, 17, 2, 18, 3, 19, 1, 17, 2, 18, 3, 19, 1, 17, 2, 18, 3, 19 };

int shuffle( int i )
{
  div_t a = div( i, 6 );
  div_t b = div( a.rem, 2 );
  return 2*a.quot + 6*b.quot + b.rem;
}

int main()
{
  for( int i=0 ; i<18 ; ++i ) cout << list[shuffle(i)] << ' ';
  cout << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

This outputs:

```
1 17 1 17 1 17 2 18 2 18 2 18 3 19 3 19 3 19
```

Just allocate the new vector, and fill it from the old one:

```
new_vector[i] = list[shuffle(i)];
```

Comment: Thanks Matt. Really appreciate it..!!